# Resize image in container with fixed height

Tags: jquery, html, css, image-resizing

So basically what I want to achieve is an image in the form of a strip across the page (with fixed height). Now if the image is too wide to fit entirely, I want to cut off the edges with "overflow: hidden" and center it. I managed to do that, but now comes the part where I fail: I don't want the image to be stretched when it's too narrow, but I want it to overflow over the top of the containing div.

[Here](http://www.apple.com/mac) you can see an example: when you scroll to the bottom you can see 3 pictures and I want to copy the way these images behave between 1200px and 1800px horizontal width of the viewport.

---

This is the basic markup I have so far:

```
<div class="piccontainer">
    <img src="picture.jpg" class="picture"/>
</div>

.piccontainer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 20vw;
    position: relative;
}
.picture {
    height: 100%
}
```

I tried several jQuery plugins which all didn't produce the expected results and I couldn't modify the CSS to produce what I need. I'm quite distraught and thus any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you paste a screenshot of the example to help us understand more?

Comment: So... whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more elegant solution would be to just use a background-image on the div.

For example:

```
.piccontainer {
  background-image:url('/bg.png');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Oh I totally forgot about the background, I had the img in there because of an earlier implementation where I wanted to achieve a parallax effect (which I gave up on because of UX issues). This is not 100% what I wanted  as you can't set a min-width of the background itself so it will just flow out of the sides of the div forever (I hope you know what I mean). But it is more than good enough, so I ended up using it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need 100% to insert image? Dod you consider to use image as background as in:

```
.anyElement{
   background-image: url("yourimage.jpeg");
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-size:contain;
   background-position:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using the image as a background image and then utilizing the `background-size:cover;` property on your image.

That way you can fix your containing element and your image will fill the container.

```
.piccontainer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 20vw;
    position: relative;
    background-image:url(picture.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center center;
}
```

Reference: [Background size on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)